# Why is broadcasting/auth not found?

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

Already uncommented at `config/app.php`:

```
App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
```

and

```
Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
```

Error:

```
POST http://pusherapp.local:8888/broadcasting/auth 404 (Not Found)
```

I am using Mamp 4 and Laravel 5.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this commands

`php artisan config:cache` 
`composer require pusher/pusher-php-server "~2.6"` (user 2.6 because 3.0 has class Pusher not found issue) 
`composer update` (just to make sure everything is up to date) 
`php artisan config:cache` (do it again)

Answer (score 0):

If you use **Jetstream with Livewire** try

`Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => 'auth:sanctum']);`

on your `boot` method in `BroadcastServiceProvider.php`.